# from django 1.4 to django 1.5- argument 'verify_exists' what s replacement?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm try to fix an app that worked with django 1.4 within a new installation where I'm using Django 1.5
when I try to syncdb I have:

```
   TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verify_exists'
```

That's because my app model.py have inside:

```
   link = models.URLField(verify_exists=True, max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

with what I d replace  'verify_exists' to make it compatible with Django1.5?

Comment: You might have to write your own custom validator to check if url does exist

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to verify the URL exists, you should do so in your form or model validation methods.

Comment: came out that even without use the 'verify_exists', the URLS are automatically verified ...so even simpler....thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 3):

Try Removing the argument

```
verify_exists = True
```

(if this argument is not in use..)

And use as below :

```
 link = models.URLField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Django 1.5 `verify_exists` is removed due to intractable security and performance issues. See more at : 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/